# Angular No muestra contenido correcto en componente ngModel Array

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, angular-cli

¿Porqué me muestra una parte del objeto en Array equivocado en el HTML del componente?

Explico, tengo mi arraglo que lo mapeo y lo recorro, básicamente lo que hago es leer un excel para meter información correctamente y luego mostrarla al usuario

```
xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json<IKey>(worksheet, { raw: true })
  .map(k => Object.keys(k).reduce((acc, cur) => (acc[cur] = k[cur].trim(), acc), <IKey>{}))
  .filter(f => f.desc && f.code.length < 5 && f.line.length < 7).map(l => {
    for (let i = (4 - l.code.length); i > 0; i--) l.code = '0' + l;
    return l;
  }).forEach(k => {
    this.Key.push(new Key(void 0, k.code, k.line, k.desc, void 0, void 0))
    console.log(new Key(void 0, k.code, k.line, k.desc, void 0, void 0))
  });
```

En el excel tiene los campos line, code & desc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la parte del html es, la cual recorre Key con ngFor y uso un ngModel para poner los valores del array y que puedan ser cambiados, pero me muestra sólo el último

```
<div *ngFor="let k of Key" class="form-group input-group">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            {{k.line}}{{k.code}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc" #desc="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="k.desc"
        autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" required />
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            <div class="pretty p-icon p-toggle">
                <input type="checkbox" name="config" #config="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="k.config" />
                <div class="state p-success-o p-on">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="state p-info-o p-off">
                    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y lo más lógico es que aparezca

Y mi problema es que se repiten los últimos valores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté cambiar el código de HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc" #desc="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="Key[i].desc"
    autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" required />
<div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
        <div class="pretty p-icon p-toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" name="config" #config="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="Key[i].config" />
```

Cambiando por Key[i] con el index, No sé si debería cambiarlo

Comment: creo que es por las referencias que creas en la template. `#config` y `#desc` Para que las necesitas?

Comment: La verdad, no tengo idea, es solo que desde que aprendí Angular lo usaban de esa forma ¿Causan algo? @hawks

Comment: son variables que se crean en la template, y le estas asignando el valor del `ngModel` se usa esto para hacer validaciones y eso. Pero tu no lo usas en la template.

Comment: Ya lo quite pero persiste el error @hawks

Comment: Es que de hecho, lo que intento es mostrarlo para así poderse cambiar el valor si el usuario lo desea

Comment: si pongo {{k.desc}} en vez de {{k.line + k.code}} me muestra lo que debería mostrarme en el input, creo que es un problema con ngModel

Comment: tiene pinta, no veo nada mal. la verdad

Comment: Encontré el error XD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582203/ngfor-not-working-correctly-with-ngmodel-angular-5-1-2 aquí. Básicamente lo que entiendo es que sobre escribe por que el nombre es identico a uno anterior, por ende, lo solucioné haciendo name="desc{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="k.desc"

Comment: ah perfecto añadelo como respuesta para que le sirva a alguien mas en el futuro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el error en otra respuesta de la página, básicamente lo que sucede es que como ponía el mismo nombre para cada input, sobre escribía la nueva con la anterior

De ese modo se debe usar el index concatenado con el name

```
<div *ngFor="let k of Key; let i = index" class="form-group input-group">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            {{k.line + k.code}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="k.desc" autocomplete="off"
        spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" required />
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            <div class="pretty p-icon p-toggle">
                <input type="checkbox" name="config{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="k.config" />
                <div class="state p-success-o p-on">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="state p-info-o p-off">
                    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```